# javascript parse/identify a regular expression from beginning to end

Tags: javascript, parsing

I am writing a tiny javascript parser in javascript.
I am at the tokenization level.

I would like to know how to recognize when a regular expression begins and ends.

For example, if I had asked the same question about how to recognize when a string 
begins and ends the answer would be:

for a string beginning with double quotes "
I know that the answer is 
string begins with double quotes "
and ends when the next double quotes " is encountered (except if preceded by backward-slash \)

any help appreciated

Comment: The `/` character must be quoted in a regular expression (`\/`) so it's like strings in that respect.

Comment: @Pointy, it's not that easy. The `/` could be either the start of a regex literal, or the division operator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Division/RegExp conflict while tokenizing Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726295/division-regexp-conflict-while-tokenizing-javascript)

Comment: Also see this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519596/when-parsing-javascript-what-determines-the-meaning-of-a-slash

Comment: @BartKiers oh yes I know that - I almost added another comment.  The point is that once you already know you're looking at a regex, you can find the end pretty easily.

Comment: @Pointy, sure, but the question is *"when a regular expression **begins** and ends"* :)

Comment: @BartKiers ah you're right; I was focusing on the part about the closing quotes.  Anyway I consider this a fascinating problem; the standard way that it's handled for JavaScript seems awful.  Pascal has a minor lexer-level ambiguity too: arrays are declared with `1..10`, but that can be solved by introducing an "integer-dot-dot" token and (slightly) ammending the grammar.  Seems like that'd be somewhat harder for JavaScript.

Comment: @BartKiers (now that I think of it that's not really an ambiguity in Pascal; it's just a lexer look-ahead issue.)

Comment: @Pointy and @ BartKiers thanks a lot for your help. I did not realize this was such a tricky problem

Comment: Zo72, did you see the links I posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The ECMAScript language specification](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/) contains a full grammar for the language (in EBNF) in [Annex A](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#annex-a). It's too large to reproduce here in its entirety, but the production for regular expressions is given as "RegularExpressionLiteral".

Comment: Too hard for what? It's the official definition of the Javascript language, so it's what you'll need to work with to correctly parse Javascript. Anything else **will** fail or give incorrect results in some circumstances.

Answer (score -2):

"In JavaScript source code, a regular expression is written in the form of */pattern/modifiers* where "pattern" is the regular expression itself, and "modifiers" are a series of characters indicating various options. The "modifiers" part is optional." [JavaScript RegExp Object](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)

Comment: That does not explain how to make a distinction between the division operator and the start of a regex literal.

Comment: I followed the example of how to determine the start and end of a string, and in the question he didn't mention he wanted to know the distinction between the division operator and the start of a regex literal. From his example, an object property could be misinterpreted as a string {"foo": "bar"}, where "foo" is not really a string. I don't think it's a good reason to downvote.

Comment: @Pablo Martinez I did not downvote you. I would not vote yours as a right answer either