# JavaScript lexer: dealing with "/"

Tags: javascript, lexer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Division/RegExp conflict while tokenizing Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726295/division-regexp-conflict-while-tokenizing-javascript)

I'm writing a JS lexer for fun and there's just one piece that's missing: the part that can chew in regexes.

Take for instance the following valid JS piece of code: `/ab+c/;`

How can a JS lexer know whether it's dealing with a regex or with
`[Operator('/'), Identifier('ab'), Operator('+'), Identifier('c'), Operator('/'), Semicolon]` ?

Comment: I've never worked on a project like this, but I'd have thought that any `/` character not preceded by an identifier would be parsed as the beginning of a regex.

Comment: I feel this is the task of the parser, not that of the lexer.

Comment: Please make your question title more descriptive than "JavaScript Lexer", which does nothing to describe (briefly) what your question is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to implement a Lexical grammar which included parsing regex. According to  [ECMA Script documenation](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-5.1.2), "A RegExp grammar for ECMAScript is given in [`15.10`](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-15.10)":

```
"The form and functionality of regular expressions is modeled 
after the regular expression facility in the Perl 5 programming language."
```

See also: [ECMAScript Lexical Conventions](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-7)

Answer (score 3):

> How can a JS lexer know whether it's dealing with a regex or with [some expression with `operator /` inside]?

Well, the lexer can't. This is something the parser should do.